# Maths with countElements and UITextField

Tags: ios, string, swift, tostring, countelements

I am making a joke app for friends and to improve my swift coding by making a LoveCalculator. The calculator finds the length of the two names of the lovers, times the lengths together, then takes that number away from 100, giving your love percentage. However, each time I try the app, it displays the number -40906 each time. Any ideas? I have tried changing the UITextField to String conversion method. I am quite a novice at swift, any help would by appreciated!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var personOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var personTwo: UITextField!

    @IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var one = toString(personOne)
    var two = toString(personTwo)

    var oneLength = countElements(one)
    var twoLength = countElements(two)

    var firstCalc = oneLength * twoLength
    var finalCalc = 100 - firstCalc

    outputLabel.text  = "%\(finalCalc)"  
}
```

Comment: PS: When run in a playground WITHOUT toString conversions or inputs from texFields/ out to Label, the code work perfectly.

Comment: Printing the the values of the variables one, two would reveal your error quickly ...

Comment: Apart from that `UITextField` problem, you also have an algorithm problem. Names longer than 10 letters will always end in a negative number.

Comment: Good point Sulthan, I don't know how I missed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`personOne` and `personTwo` are UITextFields, not texts.

Change your code to:

```
var one = toString(personOne.text)
var two = toString(personTwo.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use `outputLabel.text` to access the text of the label, you do the same with the textfield -> `textfield.text`.

[Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW13)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {


    var oneLength = countElements(personOne.text)
    var twoLength = countElements(personTwo.text)

    var firstCalc = oneLength * twoLength
    var finalCalc = 100 - firstCalc

    outputLabel.text  = "%\(finalCalc)"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code is trying to do is to `print` the `UITextField` instance into a string which would result into something like: `<UITextField: 0x7f936981ca50; frame = (225 201; 97 30); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f93698228c0>>`.

Mainly, your code should look like this in order to count the number of characters in the textfield's text:

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: AnyObject) {
  var oneLength = countElements(personOne.text)
  var twoLength = countElements(personOne.text)

  var firstCalc = oneLength * twoLength
  var finalCalc = 100 - firstCalc

  outputLabel.text  = "%\(finalCalc)"
}
```